# How can i remove the duplicate element in output / arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    int value[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6};
    int value2[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (value[i] == value[j]) 
            {
                cout << value[i] << " ";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
2 3 3 4 3
```

How can I make the output become `2 3 4` ?

Edit: I'm trying to print all numbers appearing more than once in the value array

I think I should create one more array to store value, but I stuck with it and don't know how to do it.

Comment: `for (int j = i + 1; j <= ARRAY_SIZE; j++)` you will access `value[ARRAY_SIZE]` here: `value[j]` which is outside the array. You'll get undefined behaviour. Start fixing this first.

Comment: One possible method: 1. Store all values in `value2` instead of printing them. 2. Now write another piece of code that prints all values of `value2` only once; the algotithm is similar to what you've already writtren.

Comment: Wait, I only read the question title. Are you trying to identify which elements are duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps considerably to sort your array. Then you only need two indices:

- a *write* index, starting at `0`
- a *read* index, starting at `1`

Loop over your array using the read index. For every `array[read]` that has a duplicate value at `array[read-1]`, IFF that value also does not exist at `array[write]`, then copy it over and increment your write index.

Finally, the new length of your data is equal to your write index.

---

The basic idea is this: if I have a *sorted* list of values:

```
    1  3  3  4  5  5  5  7  7  9
```

Then I can easily see if a value is a duplicate or not by comparing the current (read) with the previous.

```
         ┌────┐
 1  3  3 │4  5│ 5  5  7  7  9   --  not duplicates
         └────┘
             ↑
```

```
            ┌────┐
 1  3  3  4 │5  5│ 5  7  7  9   --  duplicate values
            └────┘
                ↑
```

The only remaining trick is to make just a single copy of that value to the *write* index, which we can do by simply looking at the last thing we wrote.

Comment: Okay, I understand the _read_ index, but how to make just a single copy of that value to the _write_ index? I mean, when the _write_ index  start from 0 to 10, it must equal some value,  Am I wrong?

Comment: Alright, I use the idea value[i] == value[i-1] && value[i] != value[i + 1], and it shows the output I want. thx

Comment: Be careful of input like `1 2 3 4 5 5` and you’re golden.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::map` to count the number of times a value is in the array. If the number appears 2 or more times, then print it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    int value[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6};
    std::map <int, int> mp;
    for(int i : value) 
        ++mp[i];
    for(const auto& p : mp) 
        if(p.second > 1)
            std::cout << p.first << ' ';
}
```

[Link](https://godbolt.org/z/x8YWz5nb3).